# How to convert value of pyomo variable from float to int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, pyomo, glpk

I'm working on an Task Scheduling problem given in Table 3 of paper [Holistic energy awareness for intelligent drones](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3486611.3486651).

[Table 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpvDb.png)

In the 6th equation: N_d = E_d/B_d

I want to convert floating value of (E_d/B_d) to an integer value of N_d.
I'm using an Abstract model on pyomo (6.4.0) on python 3.7 and glpk 4.65 solver

The basic original code written is

```
model.Drones = Set() # List of drones
model.Battery_capacity = Param(model.Drones, within=NonNegativeReals) # =170
model.Energy_total = Var(model.Drones, within=NonNegativeReals, initialize=1)
model.Charging_sessions = Var(model.Drones, within=NonNegativeReals, initialize=1)

def battery_charging_sessions_rule(model, d):
    return model.Charging_sessions[d] == (model.Energy_total[d]/model.Battery_capacity[d])
model.battery_charging_sessions = Constraint(model.Drones, rule=battery_charging_sessions_rule)
```

In this case, model.battery_charging_sessions is a floating point value which can be less than 1 also. I've tried various options like

```
model.Charging_sessions = Var(model.Drones, within=Integers, initialize=1, bounds=(0,None))
```

and using the following return statement also instead of previous one

```
    return model.Charging_sessions[d] == floor(value((model.Energy_total[d]/model.Battery_capacity[d])))
```

However, this cause the `model.Charging_sessions` forced to be 0 and it wont even be generated in results file. Using the logs I found out with no change in original code,

```
Charging_sessions[d] - (0.0058823530*Energy_total[d])
```

is lower and upper bounded by 0,where 0.0058823530 = 1/170.

While with the changes the lower and upper bound of

```
Charging_sessions[d]
```

are 0. It seems that by using floor(value()) or int(value()) the term `(0.0058823530*Energy_total[d])` is reduced to 0.

What are the ways I can get the integer value?

Comment: Which integer did you expect to get?

Comment: It depends on Energy_total[d]. If less than 170 (battery_capacity[d]) then the integer value should be 0. If less than 340 & more than 170 then 1, etc

Comment: So your last attempt using `int()` was correct, wasn't it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 using int(value(model.Energy_total[d]/model.Battery_capacity[d])) doesn't generate error, however using int(value()) put the above value as 0 no matter what is inside, defeating the purpose.

Comment: `int()` rounds down to the nearest integer, so the result is only 0 if what you pass to it is <1.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, I know, but in case of value >1 and <2 it should give 1, it is not giving that either. It only gives 0 as output, whatever value you put inside. Also I'm not giving value directly,  calculation of Energy_total[d] decides the value. So if (0.0058823530*Energy_total[d]) > 1 then the int(value((0.0058823530*Energy_total[d]))) should be 1 and not 0

Comment: Then your problem is that some number is <1 when you think it isn't. `int()` definitely returns 1 for inputs between 1 and 2. What is the `value()` function doing? It seems it is the source of the problem.

Comment: Directly, if I use int(), pyomo gives error. I read somewhere to use value(), then int.

Comment: You are totally on the wrong track here. Functions like floor() and int() are nonlinear (so using a linear solver line GLKP is just out of the question). Even worse, they are non-differentiable and not continuous, so even NLP solvers would get into trouble. Better is to to use integer variables. Floor/int can be reformulated. see eg https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862885/linear-program-with-ceiling-or-floor-functions.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for the comment. So there is no other way I can get an integer value from (E_d/N_d) ?

Comment: I think I explained the issues with truncating or rounding: it is a **nonlinear** operation. This cannot be used in a linear model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of thanks to [Erwin Kalvelagen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5625534/erwin-kalvelagen) for providing the solution.
This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862885/linear-program-with-ceiling-or-floor-functions) can work for both converting a float value to int or taking floor and taking ceil.
I've modified my code to take floor of the value. Here is the solution

```
model.Drones = Set() # List of drones
model.Battery_capacity = Param(model.Drones, within=NonNegativeReals) # =170
model.Energy_total = Var(model.Drones, within=NonNegativeReals, initialize=1)
model.Charging_sessions = Var(model.Drones, within=NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=0, bounds=(0,None))
model.Charging_sessionsTmp = Var(model.Drones, within=NonNegativeReals, initialize=1, bounds=(0,None))
        
def battery_charging_sessions_rule(model, d):
    return model.Charging_sessionsTmp[d] == model.Energy_total[d]/model.Battery_capacity[d])
model.battery_charging_sessions = Constraint(model.Drones, rule=battery_charging_sessions_rule)
    
def batt_charging_floor_val_rule_lb(model_in,d):
    return model_in.Charging_sessionsTmp[d] - 0.9999 <= model_in.Charging_sessions[d]
model.battery_charging_sessions_int_lb = Constraint(model.Drones, rule=batt_charging_floor_val_rule_lb)
    
def batt_charging_floor_val_rule_ub(model_in,d):
    return model_in.Charging_sessions[d] <= model_in.Charging_sessionsTmp[d]
```

The 3 constraints in the code basically implement following constraint

(E_d/B_d) - 0.9999 <= N_d <= (E_d/B_d)